# Get List by using Jsonpath

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I am using [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) 2.1.0 to parse a JSON String using JsonPath.

The JSON Structure is as follows:

```
{
    "status": "",
    "source": "",
    "processedRecords": 1,
    "totalRecords": 4,
    "description": "1 company(ies) added/updated, and 2 company(ies) failed",
    "payload": [{
        "Added/updated company(ies)": [
            "COM001FILE"
        ]
    }, {
        "Failed company(ies)": [{
            "id": "COM003FILE",
            "index": "NA",
            "errorMsg": [
                [
                    "INVALID_LOCATION"
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            "id": "COM002FILE",
            "index": "NA",
            "errorMsg": [
                [
                    "INACTIVE"
                ],
                [
                    "INVALID_LOCATION",
                    "INACTIVE"
                ]
            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Now the requirement is to get a list of ids whose `errorMsg` contains `INACTIVE`. to achieve this I am using filters as shown below.

```
Filter resposneFilter = Filter.filter(Criteria.where("errorMsg").is(
            "INACTIVE"));
List<Map<String, Object>> respons = JsonPath.parse(response).read(
            "$.payload[*]", resposneFilter);
```

but as output I am getting all the values in payload.

Is it possible to get the expected results?

Comment: errorMsg is an array of arrays, so you should verify if it contains an array that contains and item with text "INACTIVE"

Comment: What is expected result in your JSON when errorMsg is INACTIVE? Which json parts should it return?

Comment: @Raf It should only return Ids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking into account the JSON you provided and reading through the documentation of Jayway JsonPath. I found two solution that could help resolve you issue.

1. Solution 1 allows you to directly access the errorMsg field but, not applicbable when there are more than one companies as you have to manually loop
2. Solution 2 allows constructions of a Custom predicate that is specific to your case and is somewhat generic.

**Solution 1** 
The filter that you have seem to be correct, as shown below:

```
Filter responseFilter = Filter.filter(Criteria.where("errorMsg").is("INACTIVE"));
```

Looking into your JSON, payload can be thought of as starting point and the structure seem to be fixed the second value of `payload` array is failed companies and that is what you are interested in hence, I would write the json path as follow:

```
Map<String, Object> inactiveFailedCompany =  
           parse(json).read("$.payload[1].['Failed company(ies)'][1]", responseFilter);
```

If you notice above, I have specified `payload[1]` and I assume that is how your JSON is structured. I have also specified `['Failed company(ies)'][1]` and that is to access the company that has `INACTIVE`. You can obviously use this solution with a loop to loop through index of `['Failed company(ies)'][1]` and print the ID as follow:

```
System.out.println("Company Object > " + inactiveFailedCompany.toString());
//output: Output > {id=COM002FILE, index=NA, errorMsg=[["INACTIVE"],["INVALID_LOCATION","INACTIVE"]]}

System.out.println("Company ID > " + inactiveFailedCompany.get("id"));
//output: COM002FILE
```

Looking at the above solution, I felt bad because it is not good enough, so I read more in the documentation and came across [Roll your own predicate](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#roll-your-own) hence the Solution 2.

**Solution 2**

As explained in the documentation, I tailored the predicate's `apply` method to meet your requirements and the solution is as follow:

```
Predicate inactiveCompaniesPredicate = new Predicate() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(PredicateContext ctx) {
                if(ctx.item(Map.class).containsKey("errorMsg") && 
                    ((JSONArray)((JSONArray) ctx.item(Map.class).get("errorMsg")).get(0)).get(0).equals("INACTIVE")) {
                    return true; 
                } else {
                    return false; 
                }
            }
        };
```

Now use the above predicate as follow:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> failedCompanies = 
           parse(json).read("$.payload[1].['Failed company(ies)'][?]", List.class, inactiveCompaniesPredicate);
```

And then loop through list of companies and print the ID of the failed companies as follow:

```
for(Map<String, Object> object: failedCompanies) {
    System.out.println(object.get("id"));
    //output: COM002FILE
}
```

I would like to reflect on the scary if condition inside the predicate as follow:

**Left Part of if condition - xx**

This part filters all those that contain errorMsg field.

```
if(ctx.item(Map.class).containsKey("errorMsg") && yy)
```

**Right Part of if condition - yy**

This part makes sure that the `errorMsg` is `INACTIVE`

```
if(xx & ((JSONArray)((JSONArray) ctx.item(Map.class).get("errorMsg")).get(0)).get(0).equals("INACTIVE"))
```

Here is the sample code I used to test (I imported Jsonpath 2.1 and its dependencies as external jars to my eclipse)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import net.minidev.json.JSONArray;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Predicate;
import static com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.parse;

public class JaywayJSON {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = readFile("C:\\test_stackoverflow\\jayway.json",
                Charset.defaultCharset());

        /*
         * //Solution 1
         * 
         * Filter responseFilter =
         * Filter.filter(Criteria.where("errorMsg").is("INACTIVE"));
         * 
         * Map<String, Object> inactiveFailedCompany =
         * parse(json).read("$.payload[1].['Failed company(ies)'][1]",
         * responseFilter);
         * 
         * System.out.println("Company Object > " +
         * inactiveFailedCompany.toString()); //output: Output > {id=COM002FILE,
         * index=NA, errorMsg=[["INACTIVE"],["INVALID_LOCATION","INACTIVE"]]}
         * 
         * System.out.println("Company ID > " +
         * inactiveFailedCompany.get("id")); //output: COM002FILE
         */

        // solution 2
        Predicate inactiveCompaniesPredicate = new Predicate() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(PredicateContext ctx) {
                if (ctx.item(Map.class).containsKey("errorMsg")
                        && ((JSONArray) ((JSONArray) ctx.item(Map.class).get(
                                "errorMsg")).get(0)).get(0).equals("INACTIVE")) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };

        List<Map<String, Object>> failedCompanies = parse(json).read(
                "$.payload[1].['Failed company(ies)'][?]", List.class,
                inactiveCompaniesPredicate);

        for (Map<String, Object> object : failedCompanies) {
            System.out.println(object.get("id"));
        }
    }

    public static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding)
            throws IOException {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(encoded, encoding);
    }
}
```